# How to plot an isosurface and a 2D figure with the same scale and origin using mayavi?

Tags: python, 3d, plot, scale, mayavi

I am using mayavi to plot an iso surface from a 3D array `s` using the following piece of code:

```
src = mlab.pipeline.scalar_field(s)

fig=mlab.pipeline.iso_surface(src, color=(1.0,0.0,0.0), contours=[0.1, ], opacity=0.3)
mlab.pipeline.iso_surface(src, color=(0.0,1.0,1.0),contours=[-0.1, ], opacity=0.3)
```

Then I want to create a plot within this iso surface representing some geometrical info regarding the isosurface, for that I use a previously defined function called `geom_macro(ax)` and simply call it by typing:

```
geom_macro(fig)
mlab.show()
```

But the plot I get, although shows a good view of the isosurface it has an almost invisible plot of `geom_macro()` function, which not only is size wise not comparable in any way to the iso surface, but is in an 'out of center' location (and with a diferent x,y,z saptial orientation).  If I plot the two objects separately I get nice figures of both of them.
Just for completing the picture of what I have, the last part of the defined function (`geom_macro()`) looks like this (`AtPos` and `Geomlst` contain the (x,y,z) coordinates of what I am plotting, and `dist_btn_points` is another defined function):

```
for i in range (1, NCenter+1):
    xp, yp, zp = AtPos[i-1][0], AtPos[i-1][1], Pos[i-1][2]
    AtRadii=float(AtRadius[element[i-1]-1])
    mlab.points3d(xp,yp,zp, color=AtColor[element[i-1]-1], mode='sphere', 
        scale_factor=AtRadii, scale_mode='none')
    """ Draw connecting lines"""
    for j in range(i,NCenter):
        xp_c, yp_c, zp_c = AtPos[j][0], AtPos[j][1], AtPos[j][2]
        xp_in, yp_in, zp_in = float(Geomlst[i-1][0]), float(Geomlst[i-1][1]), float(Geomlst[i-1][2])
        xpc_in, ypc_in, zpc_in = float(Geomlst[j][0]), float(Geomlst[j][1]), float(Geomlst[j][2])
        if dist_btn_pts(xp_in, yp_in, zp_in, xpc_in, ypc_in, zpc_in) < BondMax:
            mlab.plot3d([xp,xp_c], [yp,yp_c], [zp,zp_c], color=(1.0,1.0,1.0), tube_radius=0.005)
```

I have tried changing the `extent` in the isosurface, using the minimum values of x, y and z, but the isosurface gets distorted -not sure why-) Any help will be highly appreciated.
Thank you!

Comment: I don't know if I can help you, but with the amount of detail you give I have no chance. I understand your problem -- the surface is misaligned -- but nothing about the context of what you are trying to do or how the spatial coordinates (i.e. `AtPos`) are generated.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @aestrivex .  The context is as follows, the isosurface is a molecular orbital and the function defined by geom_macro is a sticks-and-balls representation of the molecule itself.  Both the isosurface and the other plot have the same x,y,z extent, they are computed on the same grid, with the same origin.  `AtPos` is an array of the form `AtPos=[[x1,y1,z1],[x2,y2,z2],...[xn,yn,zn]]` where `n` stands for `NCenter`.  Hope these makes easier to understand what I have, if other information will be useful, please let me know.

Comment: @aestrivex , actually it might be useful to add that `Geomlst` contains the raw coordinates, and `AtPos` coordinates are defined as percentage of plotted area from `Geomlst`. Thanks.

Comment: @aestrivex I was just wondering if you have any thoughts on my question that can help to solve it.  Thanks!

Comment: Hi jealopez, your question is not inherently a bad question, but it is a difficult question to try to debug where you (as the person most familiar with the error) should do most of the work to make it easy for others to identify and reproduce the problem. I have limited time and I did not see an obvious error with your method.

If you can provide a minimal working example that reproduces the problem, (a short script that reads a few self-contained data files to feed to mayavi would be ok), I would be willing to spend some more time trying to figure out what is wrong.